# New input to NEAT not improving learning

Tags: python, neat, input-layer

I have a set of NEAT inputs for a jump game but the learning was getting stuck at one point. Consider the following screen where `Z` is the player and `X/Y` form the things we need to jump over:

```
                          XXXXXX
                           YYYY
                           YYYY
          XXXXXX           YYYY
           YYYY            YYYY
Z__________YYYY_________(z)YYYY_____
```

The `(z)` is the highest fitness I ever get to (fitness being how far to the right you get in the game). This is because the only way to get on to the second tower is to jump while on the top of the first, and no organism ever seems to figure this out. Every organism that drops to ground level after the first tower can never get over the second tower (going left back to the first tower is not one of my allowed actions).

I thought it would be enough to just add the height of the next tower as an input so that it could affect the evolution possibilities for the next generation but still no organism seems to figure it out.

I'll provide any parameters requested if you think they're important, I just assumed that adding the tower height would allow evolution to take that into account. I'm not sure which ones will be important, nor any of the config items such as population size, mutation rate, and so on.

What is the best approach to fixing this issue?